# Finding the value of pointers in memory C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

Given the dataset below and the answer shown at the bottom (b36d5c), how does one compute this value for &ptr[3]. I'm just having trouble figuring out which area of the dataset it is referring to and how you add the size to that, but I know that the answer is correct.

sizeof(int) = 4

```
Data set starting at 0xb36d00 of size 128.
            0xb36d00: 48 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 4c 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 Hm......Lm......
            0xb36d10: 50 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 30 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 Pm......0m......
            0xb36d20: 04 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 50 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 .m......Pm......
            0xb36d30: 18 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 1c 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 .m.......m......
            0xb36d40: 48 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 58 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 Hm......Xm......
            0xb36d50: 44 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 4c 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 Dm......Lm......
            0xb36d60: 00 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 0c 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 .m.......m......
            0xb36d70: 68 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 30 6d b3 00 00 00 00 00 hm......0m......
    int array[] is stored at:        0xb36d00
       int *ptr is stored at:        0xb36d28
short *shortPtr is stored at:        0xb36d28
          int x is stored at:        0xb36d38
        short y is stored at:        0xb36d14
   int ***what is defined by: (int ***)(((int **)0xb36d0c) + 2)

What is the value of &ptr[3]?
b36d5c
```

Comment: `in the image` and then we invent text as well that copy/paste feature.

Comment: We don't know the `sizeof(int)`, because your question did not specify a platform. Common `int` sizes are 2 and 4 bytes.

Comment: Updated with sizeof(int). In this case it is 4. @Stargateur the image is because copy and paste messes the formatting up quite a bit.

Comment: @ejscribner: You can put `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags around pasted text to keep it formatted.

Comment: @TurboJ: You do not need the size of `int`. `&ptr[3]` is `ptr+3`, which is, expressed in bytes, `ptr` plus three times the size of a pointer to an `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int *ptr` is said to be stored at 0xb36d28. The memory at 0xb36d28 contains 0x00b36d50 in little-endian order (and it contains that value regardless of whether pointers are four-bytes or eight, as the next four bytes are zero).  Thus, `ptr` is 0xb36d50. If pointers are four bytes, then the address of `ptr[3]` is 3•4 bytes beyond 0xb36d50, so it is 0xb36d5c. (Since this fits the known answer, we conclude pointers are four bytes, not eight.)